# The stream or file laravel\storage/logs/laravel.log could not be opened: failed to open stream on plesk server

Tags: laravel

I have hosted laravel project on Virtual Private Server(plesk) on godaddy. But it is giving above error. Website is working fine on shared server.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but the slashes are different in path. The first one is backslash, while the others are not.

Answer (score 0):

change `permission` of storage

```
sudo chmod -R 755 laravel/storage/
```

if you are using nginx the set user `www-data`

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R  laravel/
```

Comment: It is throwing error on below line :-                                                      
 response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);  in public/index.php file